# Enabling editing code while the app is running in Visual Studio (WP8)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, edit-and-continue

I am developing Windows Phone 8 apps with Visual Studio and not being able to change the code while the app is running makes me crazy. I fall for it everytime. Trying to change the code before stopping debugging.

```
Tools > Options > Edit and Continue => I unchecked Enable Edit and Continue.
```

With above steps, I was able to change the code while the app is running but now I can't change design. How can I enable design editing while the app is running, too?

Comment: As far as I know we have **never** been able to change the design layout while the program is running, other than manipulating an objects position in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way of editing the design without ever running the app. If you open your solution in Blend, you can app sample data to your bound views based off the classes that they bind to. Then when you make changes in the XAML, they will update in the design view with the sample data.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/08/29/using-sampledata-in-windows-phone-8-using-blend.aspx